# Angular-cli showing error when importing rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-cli

I get this error in angular-cli when I import rxjs, and do not know what is the source of the problem.

[angular-cli error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CojCE.png)

The path which I wrote is correct, double checked. I am new to the Angular, so feeling stuck.
Here is the source code link https://github.com/EgomortIncognitus/bookstore

books.service.ts:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator.map';

@Injectable()
export class BooksService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getAllBooks() {
    return this.http.get('data/books.json').map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

Comment: pls post the import lines of `books.service.ts`

Comment: done, thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

I believe it should be `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';` not `import 'rxjs/add/operator.map';`

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I presumed that it was some typo. Thanks again